# how to parse only HTML TAG with regex in java without jsoup

Tags: java, html, parsing, html-parsing

Hi all i need to parse only HTML TAG WITH REGEX, and left with non html tag with out jsoup

for example

```
<h1> i love india <\h1>
<xyz> name <\xyz>
<html> hey i won! <\html>
<syd> like it <\syd>
<<<<<<
<br> love you <br>  
>>>>>>>>
```

expected output is:

```
i love india
none
hey i won!
none
none
love you
none
```

i tried lot but not getting the exact answer any one help me out of this. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
        String[] array = { "<h1> i love india <\h1>",
                           "<xyz> name <\xyz>",
                           "<html> hey i won! <\html>",
                           "<syd> like i`enter code here`t <\syd>"
                        };
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(">((.[^><]+))<");
    for (String str : array ) {
        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(str);
        if(m.find()) 
          System.out.println(m.group(1));
        else
          System.out.println("none");
    }
```

Comment: thanks moti... can you please explain how m.group will work... i am confused with that... for example: i have a string like String="<h1>i like myself<\h1> if i like m.group() what is the answer  and m.group(1) and m.group(2)

Comment: Can you please explain how the regex working... how it know only html tags

Comment: if you look at the pattern: **(">((.[^><]+))<")** - the first group is any part of the string that starts with **>** and ends with **>** the second group looks into the inner parentheses where every character (dot) is collected unless it is one of >< ([^><]) one or more times (+)

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex to remove all tags:

```
s.replaceAll("<[^>]*>", "");
```

Comment: thanks for your comment, it remove all the tags but i want to remove only html tags... for non html tags it will show none.

Comment: Then you will need to specify all the possible html tags and do the right thing for each case

Comment: Is there any other way.... jaudo